# HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized error with shortcut to .jpg

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, jpeg, unauthorized

We have a directory in our web application where we allow storage of various files a user may wish to store such as pdf, word, excel, text and jpeg files among others. We decided to change that directory to a shortcut in order to support storage of the files on a different server without changing application code. This works fine for pdf, text, docx,  and xlsx but runs into a 401.3 error with jpegs (.jpg).

Our environment is .NET 4.5, Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5.

I'm baffled so decided to post here. Thanks in advance for any insight into the problem.

Comment: `401.3` usually means file permissions, have you tried looking at that?

Comment: Yes. All the permissions are there and we added some more like Everyone and IIS_IUSRS for good measure. It looks like something specific to jpegs because it doesn't happen for a few other file types we work with including pdf, text and excel. There's nothing special about any of the files.